# How to execute a selected statement from a statement list

Tags: postgresql

I want to present my users a list of simple static queries on the php-frontend so they can klick on them to get its result. For this I want to submit this query to the postgresql server and get the result of the selected query:

```
SELECT * FROM queries WHERE query_no = 2;
```

And no, I do not want to get the text of the statement. I've tried:

```
CREATE TABLE queries (
    query_no   serial primary key,
    query      text );

INSERT INTO queries ( query )
VALUES ( 'SELECT * FROM mytable1;' ),
       ( 'SELECT * FROM mytable2;' ),
       ( 'SELECT * FROM mytable3;' );

PREPARE myquery AS
    SELECT query FROM queries WHERE query_no = 2;
EXECUTE myquery;
```

Unfortunately I get the statement text and not it's result:

```
          query
-------------------------
 SELECT * FROM mytable2;
(1 row)
```

This doesn't work:

```
EXECUTE ( EXECUTE myquery );
```

Any ideas? And how is the glue between the select query_no and the table?